# Error "The publication '[Name]' does not exist." running sp_article_validation

Tags: sql-server, replication

```
DECLARE @p SYSNAME, @a SYSNAME
SET @p = N'[NAME]'
SET @a = N'[ARTICLE]'

EXEC sp_article_validation @p,@a
```

I'm using the *exact* name of the publication provided by the table MSpublications (even using `NAME` or `QUOTENAME(N'Name')` generates the same error), yet it's saying it doesn't exist.  Note that it doesn't work with any other publications either.  Yet this is what [sp_article_validation (Transact-SQL)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177511.aspx) says.

```
SELECT publication
FROM MSpublications
ORDER BY publication
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ensure you're on the *'publication'* DB so `USE [publicationDBName]` and then execute the SP.

Otherwise, try various combinations such as the below for the `NAME` variable you're passing to the SP as an argument to the SP in case it's related to it not liking the preceding `'N` which indicates that the subsequent string is in Unicode, thereby passing an `NCHAR`, `NVARCHAR` or `NTEXT` value, as opposed to `CHAR`, `VARCHAR` or `TEXT`.

- `SET @p = NAME`
- `SET @p = [NAME]`